# Не подключается к аккаунту telegram через telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Мой код

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 11111
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    print('work')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

При запуске спрашивает номер телефона и код из смс:

```
Please enter your phone (or bot token): +7111111111
Please enter the code you received: 11111
```

и после этого все виснет, print('work') не приходит

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй следующий код с учетом 2FA (ковычки не убирай там где они есть, а там где их нет не добавляй):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError

# Ваши данные API
api_id = твой api_id
api_hash = 'твой api_hash'
phone_number = 'твой номер телефона'

# Авторизация в Telegram
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start(phone_number)

# Обработка 2FA
try:
    # Попытка авторизации без пароля
    client.connect()
except SessionPasswordNeededError:
    # Требуется пароль 2FA
    password = input('Введите пароль 2FA: ')
    client.start(phone_number, password=password)
```

Это только чтобы подключиться, если хочешь сразу закрыть соединение то со следующей строки пишешь:

```
# Завершение сеанса
client.disconnect()
```

Если не сразу закрываешь соединение то уже пишешь то что тебе нужно

Comment: не помогло
если например после client.start(phone_number) дописать print('ok') то до нее не доходит, виснет все на client.start(phone_number)

пробовал с нескольких аккаунтов

Comment: До ввода пароля не доходит? Попробуй, без print(‘ok’), хотя я попробовал и с ним и у меня сразу зашло, может проблема в другом.

Comment: конечно пробовал, просто поставил чтоб понять где виснет. попробовал через pyrogram все ОК заходит, странно это все